# How to write NSPredicate Custom Object (CGFloat var) BETWEEN operation

Tags: swift, nspredicate

I want to do **Number comparison** using **BETWEEN** through *my custom object.*
I have done string comparison, however Number comparison shouts error as in the code below.

```
class CustomClass: NSObject {
    var name        : String?
    var aWidth      : CGFloat!
}
```

String comparison which works

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.name contains[c] %@","Sal")
```

HOWEVER

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.aWidth > 0 AND SELF.aWidth < 50")

let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.aWidth < 50")
```

This one totaly wrong I know.

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.aWidth BETWEEN {%@, %@}", {minWidth, maxWidth})
```

> reason: '[<test.CustomClass 0x7fe86274bfd0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key **aWidth**.'

All the search of this error took me storyboard questions.

How can I write a predicate using BETWEEN?
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE**

I also found this example about using **filter in swift** which is helpful. But I still have the problem.

```
class Person : NSObject {

    var age : CGFloat?

    init(age: CGFloat) {
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

**Filter**

```
let eventAttendees = [Person(age: 22), Person(age: 41), Person(age: 23), Person(age: 30)]
                let filteredAttendees = eventAttendees.filter({
                    $0.age < 30
                })

                for person in filteredAttendees {
                    print(person.age!)
                    }
```

When I try to use same technique, I get this **error** this time.

**First approach**

```
let array = self.testDictionary.allValues as Array

var filteredArray = array.filter( { (user: Person) -> Bool in

                    return $0.age < 30
                })
```

> Anonymous closure arguments cannot be used inside a closure that has
>   explicit arguments

**Second Approach**

```
let array = self.testDictionary.allValues as Array

var filteredArray = array.filter( { (user: Person) -> Bool in

                        return true
                    })
```

> Cannot convert value of type '(Person)' -> Bool to expected argument
>   type '(Anyobject)' -> Bool

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First of all update Xcode to use Swift 2.

Assuming you have a dictionary `[Int:CustomClass]`

```
let testDictionary = [1: CustomClass(name: "Foo", aWidth: 1.0), 2: CustomClass(name: "Bar", aWidth: 25.0), 3: CustomClass(name: "Baz", aWidth: 75.0)]
```

get the value array (the compiler knows that it contains `CustomClass` instances)

```
let array = Array(testDictionary.values)
```

then you can use the `filter` function

```
let filteredArray = array.filter { $0.aWidth > 0.0 && $0.aWidth < 50.0 }
print(filteredArray)
```

Comment: This is helpful, never used this new filter for array in swift. easy and quick.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your class by adding Constructor to initialise

```
class CustomClass: NSObject {
    var name        : String?
    var width      : CGFloat = 0.0

    // *** define constructor ***
    init(name: String, width: CGFloat) {
        self.name = name
        self.width = width
    }
}

// *** Declare Array ***
let arrObjects = NSMutableArray()

// *** create objects and add to array ***
let obj1 = CustomClass(name: "Scale", width: 200.0)
self.arrObjects.addObject(obj1)

let obj2 = CustomClass(name: "Pen", width: 40.0)
self.arrObjects.addObject(obj2)

print("1. Filter on String")   
// *** 1. Filter on String ***
var predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF.name contains[c] %@","sca")
var filteredArray = self.arrObjects.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)

for object in filteredArray
{
    let obj = object as! CustomClass
    print("\(obj.name!) \(obj.width)")
}

print("2. Filter on CGFloat")

// *** 2. Filter on CGFloat ***
predicate = NSPredicate(format: "width > %f AND width < %f",0.0, 50.0)

filteredArray = self.arrObjects.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)

for object in filteredArray
{
    let obj = object as! CustomClass
    print("\(obj.name!) \(obj.width)")
}


print("3. Filter using BETWEEN")
// *** 3. Filter using BETWEEN ***
predicate = NSPredicate(format: "width BETWEEN {%f, %f}",0.0, 50.0)
filteredArray = self.arrObjects.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(predicate)

for object in filteredArray
{
    let obj = object as! CustomClass
    print("\(obj.name!) \(obj.width)")
}
```

Referenced from [NSHipster blog by Mattt Thompson](http://nshipster.com/nspredicate/)

Comment: Thanks Dipen, this is helping me for some other case as well.

Answer (score -1):

To use Predicates with custom objects in array use as below, for swift 4+:

```
func checkIfJobIdContains(array:NSArray, job_id: String) -> Bool
{
    let temp = array.filter({ (result) -> Bool in
    let modelObj = result as! ModalMultipleJobRequestsPage
    if modelObj.job_id == job_id
    {
        return true
    }
    else
    {
        return false
    }
    })

    if temp.count != 0
    {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```